# How do I get a slice of Tensor from a 2D Tensor in Tensorflow 1.12?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, sequence

I have a 2-D tensor X with dimensions (a,b) and I need to get a 1-D slice from it , Is it possible to do an operation similar to numpy in TF such as :

```
slice = X[t,:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do that inside a Keras/TensorFlow model, you can exploit a lambda layer as follows:

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,t])(input)
```

Otherwise, you should be able to do that using the same syntax as in python, as reported here: [TensorFlow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__getitem__). Finally, you can also try the TensorFlow slice method  [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice)